# Why won't my checked list box sorting code work?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, debugging, checkedlistbox

I have a checked list box and I'm writing code for two buttons, 1 that moves all selected items upward, and one that moves each item downward. The one for moving up works, but I cant get the other one to work:

```
//Move up
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++ ) {
                if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i)) {
                    checkedListBox1.Items.Insert(i - 1, checkedListBox1.Items[i]);
                    checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i - 1, true);
                    checkedListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i + 1);
                }
            }
        }
//Move Down
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = checkedListBox1.Items.Count - 2; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i))
                {
                    checkedListBox1.Items.Insert(i + 1, checkedListBox1.Items[i]);
                    checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i + 1, true);
                    checkedListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need this in the second method:

```
checkedListBox1.Items.Insert(i + 2, checkedListBox1.Items[i]);
checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i + 2, true);
```

You're current method is inserting a copy of the current element before the following element, which bascially just puts it in the same location.

Comment: haha yep this works! I had + 2 earlier but other parts of the code didnt work, and I thought this part didnt work, so I never gave it a second try